# OSMnx Limit on using "street network from bounding box": TypeError: graph_from_bbox() takes at most 15 arguments (77 given)

Tags: osmnx

I am trying to get the drivable street network within some lat-long bounding box using the example 2a sample code from - https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/ - but I am getting this error; TypeError: graph_from_bbox() takes at most 15 arguments (77 given).

Below is what I have already tried out:

G = ox.graph_from_bbox(29.94510876, 29.93205121, 29.93678994, 29.94840128, 29.94297549, 29.96456162, 29.96164721, 29.96828055, 29.91873862, 
        29.94221035, 29.95584061, 30.04064237, 29.93609316, 30.032814, 29.96624232, 30.00497466, 30.00427683, 29.94665333, 
        29.957519, 29.943813, 29.93076, 29.927549, 29.967799, 29.969906, 29.951438, 29.975021, 29.95932, 30.00816, 29.95056, 
        30.007622, 29.951881, 30.016095, 30.031229, 30.05131, 30.044959, 29.9382, 29.919781, 30.030601, -90.04488594, 
        -90.07180566, -90.0849317, -90.12952617, -90.02696213, -90.03235984, -90.06925941, -90.09060393, -90.08716583, 
        -90.11185615, -90.12122927, -89.91899769, -90.0844343, -89.97297866, -90.01417363, -90.10830816, -90.03988187, 
        -90.07825592, -90.076855, -90.083341, -90.03282, -90.101536, -90.066648, -90.030283, -90.121145, -90.08682, 
        -90.15624, -90.0648, -90.20634, -90.106042, -90.102726, -90.019069, -89.978768, -89.955024, -89.903415, -90.0685, 
        -89.99601, -90.066334, network_type='drive')
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
ox.plot_graph(G_projected)

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(29.94510876, 29.93205121, 29.93678994, 29.94840128, 29.94297549, 29.96456162, 29.96164721, 29.96828055, 29.91873862, 
        29.94221035, 29.95584061, 30.04064237, 29.93609316, 30.032814, 29.96624232, 30.00497466, 30.00427683, 29.94665333, 
        29.957519, 29.943813, 29.93076, 29.927549, 29.967799, 29.969906, 29.951438, 29.975021, 29.95932, 30.00816, 29.95056, 
        30.007622, 29.951881, 30.016095, 30.031229, 30.05131, 30.044959, 29.9382, 29.919781, 30.030601, -90.04488594, 
        -90.07180566, -90.0849317, -90.12952617, -90.02696213, -90.03235984, -90.06925941, -90.09060393, -90.08716583, 
        -90.11185615, -90.12122927, -89.91899769, -90.0844343, -89.97297866, -90.01417363, -90.10830816, -90.03988187, 
        -90.07825592, -90.076855, -90.083341, -90.03282, -90.101536, -90.066648, -90.030283, -90.121145, -90.08682, 
        -90.15624, -90.0648, -90.20634, -90.106042, -90.102726, -90.019069, -89.978768, -89.955024, -89.903415, -90.0685, 
        -89.99601, -90.066334, network_type='drive')
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
ox.plot_graph(G_projected)
```

I am expecting to get the drivable street network within those listed lat-long bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

So the function is limited to taking only 4 arguments which define the coordinates (bounding box) and should be in the following order as mentioned in the docs ([OSMNX](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.core)).

```
osmnx.core.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west)
```

This means that one can only specify a rectangle as opposed to a generalised polygon, which I think you are trying to specify here. Hence the above error was thrown.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_bbox( -37.7860, -37.8359, 144.9903, 144.9269, network_type='drive', simplify=True, retain_all=False)
```

Comment: Correct. In particular, see the [graph_from_bbox](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.graph_from_bbox) documentation for usage instructions. If you want a graph from polygon, use the OSMnx graph_from_polygon function instead.